# Vim : How to remap <c-h> in insert mode?

Tags: editor, vim, macvim

I want to map the following for *navigation in insert mode* :

- `<c-h>` # Move left
- `<c-j>` # Move down
- `<c-k>` # Move up
- `<c-l>` # Move right

So, I added the following to my `.vimrc` :

```
inoremap <c-h> <left>
inoremap <c-j> <down>
inoremap <c-k> <up>
inoremap <c-l> <right>
```

Now,

- Left doesn't work [ Instead it deletes the left character ]
- Right works !
- Up works !
- Down works !

As I understand, `<c-h>` by default `deletes left character`. But I am unable to override it.

I even tried this :

```
 inoremap <c-j> <down>
 inoremap <c-k> <up>
 inoremap <c-l> <right>
 " Re-mapping <c-h> for insert-mode
 autocmd InsertEnter call RemapCtrlH()
 function RemapCtrlH()
     iunmap <c-h>
     inoremap <c-h> <left>
 endfunction
```

But even this didn't work either.

Comment: The problem appears to be that  you've mapped <c-j> twice, but never <c-h>

Comment: You know you can use the arrows, right?

Comment: Aaah.. that was a typo in the most important part. Fixing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, I added the following to my `.vimrc` :

```
inoremap <c-j> <down>
inoremap <c-j> <down>
inoremap <c-k> <up>
inoremap <c-l> <right>
```

Your first and second lines are the same! Change the first to the following:

```
inoremap <C-H> <Left>
```

You can confirm your mapping with:

```
:verbose imap <C-H>
```

---

#### Update following update to question, comments and acceptance

I've left the information above untouched, but to respond to the comments...

1. The clash with your "autoclose" plugin explains why this worked in the editor but not in [`$MYVIMRC`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#VIMINIT). You could work around this by putting your mapping in a plugin file in an [after-directory](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#after-directory).
2. I used title case for the `<C-H>` mapping consistent with the [notation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#<>) in the official documentation. [The documentation states](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#CTRL-%7Bchar%7D):

   > The case of `{char}` does not matter; thus <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> are equivalent.

   Should you wish to map <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd>, use `inoremap <C-S-H>` instead.
3. I'm delighted [`:verbose map`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#%3amap-verbose) helped you to track down the source of your problem! [`:verbose`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#%3averbose-cmd) is a handy tool when debugging Vim scripts.

Good luck!

Comment: I have tried this.. If I try this manually - it works. But when I do the same in vimrc - This doesn't works!

Comment: Also, you are trying to map `H` instead of `h`. Capital `H` would work as expected.

Comment: AAh.. got it fixed myself. I did `:verbose imap <C-H>` and it says `i  <C-H>       * <C-R>=<SNR>12_OpenCloseBackspace()<CR>
        Last set from ~/.vim/plugin/autoclose.vim
` - Autoclose is doing that.

Comment: Thanks for the effort !

Comment: @YugalJindle: Happy to help, I've updated my answer with a little more information for future reference.

Comment: AAh.. got it fixed myself. I did `:verbose imap <C-H>` and it says `<C-H>` conflict with  `Plug 'jiangmiao/auto-pairs'`  and  `autoclose.vim`

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

```
inoremap <c-p> <up>
inoremap <c-n> <down>
inoremap <c-b> <left>
inoremap <c-f> <right>
```

Advantage: they're widely used in all programs.